# SSH server на Android

Tags: android, ssh, сервер

Можно настроить ssh сервер на андроиде? Как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно установить приложение из Android Market: [SSHDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid), которое реализует SSH-сервер для Android-телефона. Приложение сделано на основе [Dropbear SSH](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html).

Comment: есть по нему мануал ?

Comment: Оно работает без рута?

Comment: Мануала я не видел. Работает без рута.